# How to upload a R data frame into a google drive ?

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I am using googledrive package from CRAN. But, function - drive_upload lets you upload a local file and not a data frame. Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Uploading to Google Drive and Google Sheets is not exactly the same thing: which do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can find no way to push the dataframe up directly, but just to document for others trying to get the basics accomplished that this question touches upon is with the following code that writes a local .csv and then bounces it up through `tidyverse::googledrive` to express itself as a googlesheet.

```
write_csv(iris, 'df_iris.csv')
drive_upload('df_iris.csv', type='spreadsheet')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save a data_frame in question to a local file. Most basic options would be saving to CSV or saving an RData.

Example:

```
test <- data.frame(a = 1)
tempFileCon <- file()
write.csv(test, file = tempFileCon)
rm(test)
load("test.Rds")
exists("test")
```

Since clarified it is not possible to use temporary file we could use a file connection.

```
test <- data.frame(a = 1)
tempFileCon <- file()
write.csv(test, file = tempFileCon)
```

And now we have the file conneciton in memory that we can use to provide for other functions. Caveat - use literal object name to address it and not quotations like you would with actual files.

Comment: I do not want to save the file into local. I need to upload it to google drive directly. Your approach needs me to save it locally

Comment: If you are constrained to not being able to write a temporary file to be discarded then the solution would require a bit more work. Are you sure you cannot have a temporary file created?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about it. I cannot create a temp file.

Comment: You could use file(). I have updated the answer to take into account your clarification.

Comment: how exactly do we use `drive_upload` after the file connection step?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using gs_add_row from googlesheets package. This API accepts dataframes directly as input parameter and uploads data to the specified google sheet. Local files are not required.

From the help section of ?gs_add_row:

"If input is two-dimensional, internally we call gs_add_row once per input row."

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways. Like mentioned by others, a local file can be created and this can be uploaded. It is also possible to create a new spreadsheet in your drive. This spreadsheet will be created in the main folder of your drive. If you want it stored somewhere else, you can move it after creation.

```
# install the packages
install.packages("googledrive", "googlesheets4")

# load the libraries
library(googledrive)
library(googlesheets4)


## With local storage
# Locally store the file
write.csv(x = iris, file = "iris.csv")

# Upload the file
drive_upload(media = "iris.csv", type='spreadsheet')


## Direct storage
# Create an empty spreadsheet. It is stored as an object with a sheet_id and drive_id 
ss <- gs4_create(name = "my_spreadsheet", sheets = "Sheet 1")

# Put the data.frame in the spreadsheet and provide the sheet_id so it can be found
sheet_write(data=iris, ss = ss, sheet ="Sheet 1")

# Move your spreadsheet to the desired location
drive_mv(file = ss, path = "my_creations/awesome location/")
```